# How to run and test Cloud-init locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, devops, provisioning, cloud-init

Recently, I have been provisioning cloud servers using [Cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I like it and it is sufficient for my usecase which is simple configuration management.

To run and test Cloud-init scripts, I always have to spin up a new cloud instance and wait for several minutes to check whether it went through or not. It hugely impacts my productivity.

So, what is the best way to run Cloud init locally (on a virtual machine)? Ansible or Chef script can be executed locally in an idempotent matter.

I tried installing cloud-init package and executing `cloud-init` command. Apparently, it looks for some [metadata files](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/instancedata.html) created by the Cloud Provider. Is it possible to mock those files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Multipass recently to test Cloud-init scripts locally. It meets my requirements.

https://multipass.run

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. How does multipass help test cloud-init without instantiating a new VM each time?

Comment: Otherwise, I had to provision a Cloud VM each time to test the cloud-int changes.